# What is a challenge swap and how do I use it?

Tags: halo-infinite

My battle pass has rewarded me a 'challenge swap'

[image: Challenge swap item]

What is this item for and how do I use it?

Answer (score 3):

A challenge swap does what it's name says on the tin. Open your challenge list on the main multiplayer screen. From there you can select a challenge to swap out to a new one.